# Is there a way to load the results of a teradata show stats values into a table?

Tags: optimization, teradata, database-administration

I know that you can determine whether a table is block level compressed by executing a show command on the stats values:

```
show stats values on DBname.TABLEname
-- BLCPctCompressed >0 means yes
```

My question is whether there is a way to access these results procedurally or in batch?  I am working on researching ways to save space on my Teradata system and hunting for tables that are not BLC can be time consuming if you go table by table.  I wanted to inquire if there was procedural way to report all the tables in my database with a Y/N for BLC before doing something more complex like constructing a shell script that exports the `show stats values on <table>` result to a file and runs a perl script to evaluate the BLC line for the Y/N.  Perhaps there is a way to insert the results of the show into a table?  Something akin to `create volatile table vt_stat_rslt as (show stats values on db.table) with data on commit preserve rows`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're only looking for BLC info, this can be found in the `BLCCompRatio` column of `dbc.StatsV`:

```
 select * from dbc.STatsV where StatsId = 0
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for!  Can you help me understand what the statsId  = 0 line is for?

Comment: `StatsId = 0` returns the *summary stats*, i.e. table level information.

Answer (score 0):

No, the output of a HELP or SHOW can only be returned to the client. It can't be used as a subquery / CTE or accessed in a Stored Procedure.

Consider running the `ferret` utility directly on the database nodes (one command can list information about many tables).

You might also look at the `CreateFsysInfoTable` / `PopulateFsysInfoTable` macros (see the *SQL Functions, Operators, Expressions, and Predicates* manual) to obtain and store information about one table at a time.

Comment: dnoeth's response is better. I answered the surface question, he addressed the underlying motivation for the question.

Answer (score 0):

Collect statistics information is usually stored in `dbc.columnstatsv` or `dbc.indexstatsv`. You van check these two dbc views and see if it helps.

Comment: Those views are legacy since several releases, actually they're just a subset of `dbc.StatsV`